# Rails S3 glob (wildcard file search)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

Locally I can do `Dir.glob("path/to/my/*.jpg")`, to get an array of paths that match. How can I do this with S3 storage?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, S3 allows a "prefix" (with wildcard at the end), but not wildcards halfway through the path. I created a method to use the prefix for the search up to the first `*`, then filter out the rest by switching to a regex.

Here's the wildcard search:

```
# /app/services/S3.rb
class S3
  class << self

    # this is designed to imitate Dir.glob, so '*' is a wildcard
    def glob(filename_pattern)
      prefix = filename_pattern.sub(/\*.*/, "")
      regex = /.*/
      if filename_pattern =~ /\*/
        regex = Regexp.new filename_pattern[/\*.*/].gsub("*", ".*")
      end
      bucket.objects(prefix: prefix).map(&:key).select{|key| key.match(regex)}
    end

    private

    def bucket
      @bucket ||= Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION']).bucket(ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET'])
    end
  end
end
```

An example of calling this class: `S3.glob("images/doggos/*.jpg")`